# how to convert array to object for discordjs

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How to convert an array to an object like {}
The result I receive in the code below is an array

currently the result is `[ { result: result} ]` but I want to convert it to `{ result:result }`

I tried `fromEntries`, But it shows result: `{ undefined: undefined }`

Here is the Code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "wki",
    aliases: [],
    run: async (client, message, args, color) => {
        const query = args.join(" ")

        wikia.search(query).then(results => {
            console.log(results)
            const obj = Object.fromEntries(results);
            console.log(obj);

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array only contains single element, you can just access it using `index`:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "wki",
    aliases: [],
    run: async (client, message, args, color) => {
        const query = args.join(" ")

        wikia.search(query).then(results => {
            console.log(results)
            const obj = results[0];
            console.log(obj);

        });
    }
}
```